# Updating state data containing a nested array of objects

Tags: reactjs

My state "data" consist of the following nested array of objects

```
{
    "message": "Fetched films successfully.",
    "films": [
        {
            "_id": "640685ea5d0f00f7f2e4c5b5",
            "title": "Catwoman: Hunted",
            "imageUrl": "images/5.png",
            "releaseDate": "2023-03-16T04:00:00.000Z",
            "reviewcnt": 4,
            "reviewavg": 3,
            "userlikecnt": 3
        },
        {
            "_id": "640685f05d0f00f7f2e4c5bf",
            "title": "Troll",
            "imageUrl": "images/1.jpg",
            "releaseDate": "2023-01-23T04:00:00.000Z",
```

I'm trying to decrement the userlikecnt of filmID : 640685ea5d0f00f7f2e4c5b5 as follows:

```
setData(prevState=>{
    prevState.films.map(film=>{
        if(film._id===id)
            return{
                ...film,
                userlikecnt:film.userlikecnt-1,
            }
            return film;
        })
    })
```

Where id containts "640685ea5d0f00f7f2e4c5b5". The above code isn't working

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not returning the modified state after mapping over the films array. You can modify your code:

```
setData(prevState => {
  return {
    ...prevState,
    films: prevState.films.map(film => {
      if (film._id === id) {
        return {
          ...film,
          userlikecnt: film.userlikecnt - 1
        };
      }
      return film;
    })
  };
});
```

Comment: this is working however I don't understand the first 4 lines of code. Could you explain?

Comment: Your state consists of not just films, there's also a message in there, therefor you need to return the whole object and override just the films. So by doing return {... prevState, films: ...} what you're saying is copy over everything that was in prevState and override the films. Hope this is clear for you